# VIM : go to new empty line, keep the cursor in the previous column

Tags: vim, vi

Let's say my cursor at Line 1 Column 5 :

```
1 2 3 4 [5]   <- my cursor is here
              <- empty new line
```

what setting do I need so when I press down, here is what i get :

```
1 2 3 4 5
        []     <- Line 2, Col 5
```

---

Normally pressing down will make the cursor return to the first column, because the new line is empty, like this one :

```
1 2 3 4 5
[]
```

Once in my life, I ever got this behaviour, but I forgot what I do that time.

I already try many keyword in google, but I found no answer :(

This behaviour will help me a lot on writing cleaner and nice looking code :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `:set virtualedit=all`, which you can put in your `.vimrc` file to always get this behavior.

Note that this only works if you already have a blank line below. If the file hasn't been extended that far, `j` will still do nothing.